# Table join and sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, join

I have an SQL table that stores process data logged from an automation process. The table stores a variable name, logged value, timestamp. The table looks like this:

```
VariableName | VariableValue | Timestamp
------------------------------------------
   Tag_1     |       1       |   Time_1  
   Tag_1     |       5       |   Time_2  
   Tag_1     |       4       |   Time_5  
   Tag_1     |       8       |   Time_7   
   Tag_2     |       3       |   Time_1  
   Tag_2     |       4       |   Time_3  
   Tag_2     |       5       |   Time_6  
   Tag_2     |       7       |   Time_7  
    ...
```

Values of the variables are logged "on change", therefore they appear in the table with different timestamps.

To be able to export the data and use them for further processing we need to sort the table and represent it in a different form, i.e.:

```
Timestamp | Tag_1 | Tag_2
--------------------------
  Time_1  |   1   |   3  
  Time_2  |   5   |   -  
  Time_3  |   -   |   4  
  Time_5  |   4   |   -  
  Time_6  |   -   |   5  
  Time_7  |   8   |   7
```

As you can see, there are some "blind spots" in the table representing the variable values, which corresponds to the fact that simply at this time, there was no value logged for the tag, namely no change in the tag value with respect to the previously logged value.

How do I achieve this with SQL? I most probably need a new table with the structure above. However, it needs to be created dynamically, since number of columns depends on the number of variables logged (Tag_1, Tag_2, etc.).

Creating the table and querying the database is not a problem since I use VB scripts for that purpose. I do not however know how to formulate the query (a join???) to achieve that structure...

Comment: Hi There. Have you looked at or are you familiar with Pivot Tables. This should give you what you want. Lookup SQL PIVOT.

Answer (score 3):

Yo could use this [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) query:

```
SELECT TimeStamp, Tag_1, Tag_2
FROM   mytable
PIVOT  (
         MIN(VariableValue)
         FOR VariableName IN ([Tag_1], [Tag_2])
       ) AS PivotTable;
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/DIZUI50497). Output:

```
TimeStamp | Tag_1 | Tag_2
----------+-------+-------
  Time_1  |   1   |   3
  Time_2  |   5   | (null)
  Time_3  |(null) |   4
  Time_5  |   4   | (null)
  Time_6  |(null) |   5
  Time_7  |   8   |   7
```

You cannot do this with a dynamic list of columns directly, but in a programming environment (or in TSQL with [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql)) you could build this query dynamically.

Comment: `Sub-select` isn't needed in this case. It can be `..from mytable PIVOT (MIN(VariableValue)..` and it should be dynamic OP has mentioned `Tag_1, Tag_2, etc.`

Comment: Updated, @Pரதீப். Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using a [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) with a [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

First the @Columns variable for the column names is calculated.

The LogTable is used to get the tag names. But if you have a reference table with the known tags then it might be better to base it on that reference table.  Since log tables tend to get big.

```
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max);

SELECT @Columns = concat(@Columns+', ',QUOTENAME(VariableName)) FROM LogTable GROUP BY VariableName;

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT VariableName, VariableValue, [Timestamp] FROM LogTable) q
PIVOT (MAX(VariableValue) FOR VariableName IN ('+ @Columns +')) p';

EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: Good solution! The last line can just be `EXEC (@SQL);`

Comment: @trincot True, changed it back.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect Representation of results.

[image]

This might work. I note that Tags might not necessarily be just Tag_1, Tag_2, in that case a more dynamic approach would be required.

```
  SELECT 
[TimeStamp], ISNULL(Max(Tag_1),'-') as Tag_1,  ISNULL(Max(Tag_2),'-') as Tag_2
FROM
(SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_3) as ST
PIVOT
(
MAX(VariableValue)
FOR VariableName in ([Tag_1], [Tag_2])
) AS PT
 Group By [TimeStamp]
```

Correct Representation of results
[image]

Comment: `Group By` won't make any difference

Comment: Surely it does as the requested output is grouped by TimeStamp? Otherwise, TimeStamp will be repeated as per my screen shot (without grouping) But feel free to correct my solution. We are all learning.

Comment: The last result table seems to correspond to what I want to achieve. As pointed out, the data that I will work on will be log data, hence the table might be quite big. I hope the solution will allow me to use arbitrary variable names. Even though I know upfront what are the variable names, it might happen that they will not appear in the log table at all, since a value of the tag did not change for instance.

Comment: ... and one more comment: would it be better to execute the query dynamically, i.e. through a  script that would implement a for loop for instance or will the query above do the job?

Comment: @SQLAndOtherStuffGuy, Timestamp is automatically grouped by the use of the `pivot` syntax. See it run on http://rextester.com/DIZUI50497. If this is not the case in your environment, there is something wrong (either in the data, the kind of engine, or still something else).

Comment: If TAG values can change then you would need to build up the PIVOT query dynamically.

Comment: @tincot, Cool. I'll check that out. Thanks for pointing that out.